# Solve the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{(x+1)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{(x+1)}$$ given that $x=80$ when $t=0$. Give your answer in the form $x=f(t)$.

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = -\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{(x+1)} \\
\frac{dt}{dx} & = \frac{-5}{\sqrt{(x+1)}} \\ 
\int-\frac{1}{5}dt & = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)}}dx \\
-\frac{1}{5}t & = 2\sqrt{(x+1)} \\ 
-\frac{t}{10} & = \sqrt{(x+1)} \\ 
\left(-\frac{t}{10}\right)^2 & = x+1 \\ 
x & = \left(-\frac{t}{10}\right)^2-1+C \\ 
\end{align}

Let $x=80$ and $t=0$
\begin{align}
80 & = -1+C \\
C & = 81 \\ 
\end{align}

Answer in the Mark Scheme is $C=18$
$$x=\left(9-\frac{t}{10}\right)^2-1$$

Comment: You should after the integration (fourth line) have $2\sqrt{x+1}=-\frac{1}{5}t+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put $+C$ in the right place. You should have $C-\frac{t}{10}=\sqrt{x+1}$. Solve for $C$ here, then isolate $x$.

Comment: Is there a difference between that equation and $-\frac{t}{10}=\sqrt{x+1}+C$

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth No. Your $C$ is just the negative of my $C$.

Comment: The important step is that the $C$ is introduced after integration and before further manipulation. Zachary's $C$ will end up in the bracket being squared.